# Convert hexadecimal notation into latitudinal hours and minutes

Tags: java, hex

Given:

- `0x12E7` represents 48°39'
- `0x3026` represents 123°26'

What is the *most efficient* way to convert the representation of those latitudes into two variables:

- hours
- minutes

Where the first example would be:

- hours = 48
- minutes = 39

And the second example:

- hours = 123
- minutes = 26

**Edit**

Latitude is an `int`.

Comment: So, is the initial representation a string or an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int l = 0x12E7;
int h = l / 100;
int m = l % 100;
System.out.printf("%d°%d'", h, m); // 48°39'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `String` value:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("12E7", 16);
int hours = i / 100;
int minutes = i % 100;
```

Or you can use the `0x...` format directly:

```
int i = 0x12E7;
int hours = i / 100;
int minutes = i % 100;
```

Comment: If you remove `0x` from the String in `Integer#parseInt()`, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
hours = 0x12E7 / 100;
minutes = 0x12E7 % 100;
```